# App crashing in iPhone 5s and iPad when trying to display an SKScene not in simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

Ok so I have an app with 40 levels and i have a scroll view with buttons that have different tags for each level (level 1 has a tag of 1, level 17 has a tag of 17, ect...)

Each of these levels have an SKScene class (level1.h/level1.m, level35.h/level35.m, ect) and i have imported each of these into my ViewController.m like so:

```
#import "level1.h"
#import "level2.h"
#import "level3.h"
#import "level4.h"
#import "level5.h"
#import "level6.h"
#import "level7.h"
#import "level8.h"
#import "level9.h"
#import "level10.h"
#import "level11.h"
#import "level12.h"
#import "level13.h"
```

you get the idea

and then i have one action linked to all 40 button (with 40 tags) up to the same function. then i did this:

NOTE: you probably don't need to read more than like 2 case statements and the very end and the beginning...i just wanted to be thorough and provide all of it.

```
-(IBAction)levelButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    UIButton *button = (UIButton*)sender;
    NSLog(@"button tag: %li",(long)button.tag);
    // Configure the view.

    skView = (SKView *)self.view;
    SKScene *scene;

    if (button.tag > [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"currentLevel"]) {
        NSLog(@"level not available");
    } else {
        switch (button.tag) {
            case 1:
                // Create and configure the scene.
                scene = [level1 sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
                scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
                break;
            case 2:
                // Create and configure the scene.
                scene = [level2 sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
                scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
                break;
            case 3:
                // Create and configure the scene.
                scene = [level3 sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
                scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
                break;
            case 4:
                // Create and configure the scene.
                scene = [level4 sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
                scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
                break;
            case 5:
                // Create and configure the scene.
                scene = [level5 sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
                scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
                break;
            case 6:
                // Create and configure the scene.
                scene = [level6 sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
                scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
                break;
            case 7:
                // Create and configure the scene.
                scene = [level7 sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
                scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
                break;
            case 8:
                // Create and configure the scene.
                scene = [level8 sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
                scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
                break;
            case 9:
                // Create and configure the scene.
                scene = [level9 sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
                scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
                break;
            case 10:
                // Create and configure the scene.
                scene = [level10 sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
                scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
                break;
            case 11:
                // Create and configure the scene.
                scene = [level11 sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
                scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
                break;
            case 12:
                // Create and configure the scene.
                scene = [level12 sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
                scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
                break;
            case 13:
                // Create and configure the scene.
                scene = [level13 sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
                scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
                break;
            case 14:
                // Create and configure the scene.
                scene = [level14 sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
                scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
                break;
            case 15:
                // Create and configure the scene.
                scene = [level15 sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
                scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
                break;
            case 16:
                // Create and configure the scene.
                scene = [level16 sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
                scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
                break;
            case 17:
                // Create and configure the scene.
                scene = [level17 sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
                scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
                break;
            case 18:
                // Create and configure the scene.
                scene = [level18 sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
                scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
                break;
            case 19:
                // Create and configure the scene.
                scene = [level19 sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
                scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
                break;
            case 20:
                // Create and configure the scene.
                scene = [level20 sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
                scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
                break;
            case 21:
                // Create and configure the scene.
                scene = [level21 sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
                scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
                break;
            case 22:
                // Create and configure the scene.
                scene = [level22 sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
                scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
                break;
            case 23:
                // Create and configure the scene.
                scene = [level23 sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
                scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
                break;
            case 24:
                // Create and configure the scene.
                scene = [level24 sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
                scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
                break;
            case 25:
                // Create and configure the scene.
                scene = [level25 sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
                scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
                break;
            case 26:
                // Create and configure the scene.
                scene = [level26 sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
                scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
                break;
            case 27:
                // Create and configure the scene.
                scene = [level27 sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
                scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
                break;
            case 28:
                // Create and configure the scene.
                scene = [level28 sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
                scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
                break;
            case 29:
                // Create and configure the scene.
                scene = [level29 sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
                scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
                break;
            case 30:
                // Create and configure the scene.
                scene = [level30 sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
                scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
                break;
            case 31:
                // Create and configure the scene.
                scene = [level31 sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
                scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
                break;
            case 32:
                // Create and configure the scene.
                scene = [level32 sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
                scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
                break;
            case 33:
                // Create and configure the scene.
                scene = [level33 sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
                scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
                break;
            case 34:
                // Create and configure the scene.
                scene = [level34 sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
                scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
                break;
            case 35:
                // Create and configure the scene.
                scene = [level35 sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
                scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
                break;
            case 36:
                // Create and configure the scene.
                scene = [level36 sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
                scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
                break;
            case 37:
                // Create and configure the scene.
                scene = [level37 sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
                scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
                break;
            case 38:
                // Create and configure the scene.
                scene = [level38 sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
                scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
                break;
            case 39:
                // Create and configure the scene.
                scene = [level39 sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
                scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
                break;
            case 40:
                // Create and configure the scene.
                scene = [level40 sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
                scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
        [skView presentScene:scene];
        //levelSelect.hidden = YES;
        scrollView.hidden = YES;
        quitButton.hidden = NO;
    }

}
```

So i submitted the code to apple and they said it crashed in iPad and iPhone 5s. I have no idea what to do so PLEASE help!!! I looked through everything and it just isn't working.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Have you actually run the app on a device (other than the simulator)? What "just isn't working"? And what error is Apple getting?

Comment: I have run it on my iPod Touch 5th ten but other than that i have no device. I don't have any 300-800+ dollars to spare to get all these devices.

Comment: They said that the program crashed whenever they tap a level button.

Comment: You might find crash logs in iTunes connect.

Comment: Often when an app crashes on the device and not on the simulator it's a memory issue...